# Assigning licences in office 365 with powershell using csv

Tags: powershell, csv, office365

So i'm trying to assign licences to users within a csv file. Some users will have more than 1 licences e.g powerbi pro, e3. Issue is if a user doesn't need two licences the field in the csv file is left blank which causes errors in my code

Here is my Powershell code

```
Connect-MSOLService
    $users = Import-csv 'C:\User Creation\ADUsers.csv'-delimiter ","
    foreach ($user in $users)
    {
        $Firstname = $User.Firstname
        $Lastname   = $User.Lastname
        $upn= "$Firstname.$Lastname@domain.com"
        $usagelocation= $user.Usagelocation
        $SKU= $user.License
        $SKUS= $user.Licenses
        Set-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName $upn -UsageLocation $usagelocation 
        Set-MsolUserLicense -UserPrincipalName $upn -AddLicenses $SKU,$SKUS
 }
```

Any help will be appreciated.
Works fine if the csv field is filled with a valid licence but when its blank it errors. I have tried using an if statement

```
 {if($user.Licenses -eq "") {$user.Licenses="domain:POWER_BI_STANDARD"}
```

Still gives error

Comment: You could ignore if statements and just do something like `Set-MsolUserLicense -UserPrincipalName $upn -AddLicenses ($SKU,$SKUS | Where-Object {$_})`

Comment: what goes into Where-Object {$_}) ( i'm a novice with this) if i put ```($SKU,$SKUS |Where-Object {$_Licenses -eq ""} it runs fine. users with licences gets assigned but users with blanks with 1 licences and a blank nothing gets assigned at all

Comment: You just leave it `Where-Object {$_}`. When `$SKU,$SKUS` is piped into `Where-Object`, each one of those objects becomes `$_` one at a time. If they are not null and do not contain empty values, then the where condition will evaluate to true for that object and only output that object(s). The result is an array of string objects that contain non-empty values.

Comment: It worked lool. I've been at work trying to sort this myself all day, Thanks a bunch :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the following modification to the `Set-MsolUserLicense` command.

```
Set-MsolUserLicense -UserPrincipalName $upn -AddLicenses ($SKU,$SKUS | Where-Object {$_})
```

**Explanation:**

The syntax `$SKU,$SKUS` produces an array of values that are assigned to each of those variables. A similar output is produced using `@($SKU,$SKUS)`. When an array is piped (`|`) into `Where-Object`, each object within that array becomes the current pipeline object (`$_` or `$PSItem`). The script block (`{}`) contents for `Where-Object` performs a comparison or conditional check. In this case, `$_` will be evaluated as a `boolean` to see if it returns `True` or `False`. If it returns `True`, that object will be returned. Otherwise, the object will not be returned. Using the `()` around the expression, allows the entire output to be returned at once to the `-AddLicenses` parameter.

---

See [Where-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object?view=powershell-6) for more information about using `Where-Object` and its script block syntax